# Cannot find compilation library location for package ... After run asp.net core 2 published project on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, publish

After run my published project (Asp.net core 2) on iis get this error :

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'...

And i install it from nuget. After run again on iis get this error :

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Data.SqlClient'.

And i install it from nuget so, after run again my project on iis get this error :

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml'

And this process continues.

**Web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LibraryProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\log\stdout">
<environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b874d2d9-471b-494a-828c-257173c5a413-->
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this site. Probably helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @jcvegan Thanks, but i think iis errors in authorize action. because error occures in every actions with authorize.

Comment: I figured out the reason for the bug after logging in. any idea to solve it?

Comment: Can you put any code where the authorization is failing?